# Why is $\log\frac{1}{2} = -\log(2)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Why does $\log\frac{1}{2} = -\log(2)$
What rule is being used?

EDIT:  Wow, that was fast.  Thanks for the replies.  I saw it shortly after I posted it.

Comment: Since $e^{-x}$ is $\frac{1}{e^x}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply the rule $\log(a/b) \equiv \log a - \log b$.

Comment: Congruent to? Why not just use "="?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The symbol $\equiv$ is commonly used in identities, e.g. $\cos 2x \equiv \cos^2x - \sin^2x$. $\log(a/b) \equiv \log a - \log b$ means that $\log(a/b) = \log a - \log b$ for all $a$ and $b$. (Where I assume $a,b > 0$.

Comment: Happy 10k :) ${}$

Comment: @CliveNewstead Thanks :)

Comment: Wow, that was fast.  Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: @JackOfAll Everybody here was eager to help you out. Upvote their answers and pick one to accpet and reward. ;)

Comment: Just curious, commonly used where?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62974.html).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\frac{1}{2}=2^{-1}$ and $\log{a^b}=b\log{a}$

Answer (score 3):

Because of the generat property of logarithms

$$\log\frac xy=\log
 x-\log y\implies \log\frac12=\log 1-\log 2=-\log 2$$

Answer (score 2):

Recall what $y=\log_a(x)$ means. This means, given $a$ and $x$, $y$ is such that $x=a^y$. Hence, $$\dfrac1x = \dfrac1{a^y} = a^{-y}$$
Hence, $\log_a\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) = -y = -\log_a(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

All of the above replies are exactly right. Here's a "conceptual" way of looking at it. We want to prove that, in general, $ \log_b \left( \dfrac {1}{x} \right) = - \log_b (x) $. Well, think of it this way.

Let $ \log_b \left( x \right) = p $.

Then, $ x = b^p $. That is, we have to raise $b$ to the $p$th power to get $x$. But to get $\dfrac{1}{x}$, we know, from exponential properties, that we have to raise $b$ to the same power but negative of that. Why? Simply because $$ b^{-p} = \dfrac {1}{b^p} $$ by definition. Thus, $ b^{-p} = \dfrac {1}{x} $, so we have our result.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\log ab = \log a + \log b$ and $\log a^b = b \log a$. You should verify these identities using whatever definition of the natural logarithm is at your disposal. Accompanied by the fact that $\log 1 = 0$, the identity in the original post follows.

Answer (score 1):

This logarithm rule, $\log \frac{x}{y}=\log x- \log y$, is really from the exponent rule $\frac{x^a}{a^b}=x^{a-b}$. See how they are similar?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2=a^{\log_a{\frac{1}{2}}}a^{\log_a{2}}=a^{\log_a{\frac{1}{2}}+\log_a{2}}=a^0$

$\log{\frac{1}{2}}+\log{2}=0$

Therefore:

$\log{\frac{1}{2}}=-\log{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$g^{\log_{g}a}=a$ for $g>0\wedge g\neq0\wedge a>0$. This can be
used as definition of $\log_{g}a$.

Based on that (not using any
rules for logs) you find:

$10^{\log\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}=2^{-1}=\left(10^{\log2}\right)^{-1}=10^{-\log2}$
so $\log\frac{1}{2}=-\log2$.

Here $g=10$ and $\log a$ is by convention an abbreviation of $\log_{10}a$.